# How to control code within stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, stored-procedures

I have one stored procedure MySproc with following two queries

```
INSERT INTO STG 

SELECT ID,AMT,DATE FROM CUSTOMER

UPDATE STG SET AMT = null
```

I dont want to run the update everytime I run MySproc. What is the best way to control what I want to run within MySproc?

Comment: Just comment it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your procedure as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myPROC @RUNUPDATE INT = 1
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO STG 

SELECT ID,AMT,DATE FROM CUSTOMER
IF @RUNUPDATE = 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE STG SET AMT = null
    END

END
```

When you run call your proc, you can pass in a value of 1 or 0 depending upon whether you wish to run the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
INSERT INTO STG
SELECT ID,AMT=NULL,DATE FROM CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO STG
SELECT ID,NULL,DATE FROM CUSTOMER
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.